# Power measurement in star three phase balanced load

Tags: power-supply, power, dc, three-phase, star

I had a doubt, in a balanced star three phase arrangement:

Using two wattmeter method, we obtain power readings as W1 and W2. (which may be unequal).

Let us take W1=5 watt and W2= 6 watt for instance and phase current to be 10 ampere.

However from the definition of real power, we know that power will be dissipated in resistor only.

So if I use power= i^2 *r,

In the first case, when power is 5 watt,

r=5/100 ohm while in second case it is 6/100 ohm

However, we said that it is a balanced arrangement, then how come the value of resistances is different.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if there's neutral current you will need three wattmeters.

Comment: there isnt neutral current @Jasen

Comment: How the current is got for your calculation? Is the three phase outlet symmetric (=equal phase voltages and 120 degrees shifts)? What happens if you swap the meters? Do they still keep their readings? Is the load said to be symmetric or is it a measured fact? If you have a 3 phase transformer it can quite far from ideal. Is there one? The specs of it?